# Changing the tab sizes of a Notebook widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to change the size of the tabs in a tkinter Notebook widget, but I haven't been able to find anything that actually changes the width and height of the tabs. Is there not a direct way to change them? Or is there some way to get around it? I'm currently using python 3 if that changes anything.

Comment: You are not able to set a tab width. However you can adjust the tab text with spaces to obtain a width.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that could work for the width. Still have the issue of height though. I guess changing the size of the text might adjust the tab sizes, but I'm not sure on how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you want padding in the ttk notebook's tabs?

In which case you can use a custom style, which you can adjust to your taste for colors padding etc.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create( "MyStyle", parent="alt", settings={
        "TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0] } },
        "TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [100, 100] },}})

style.theme_use("MyStyle")

a_notebook = ttk.Notebook(root, width=200, height=200)
a_tab = ttk.Frame(a_notebook)
a_notebook.add(a_tab, text = 'This is the first tab')
another_tab = ttk.Frame(a_notebook)
a_notebook.add(another_tab, text = 'This is another tab')
a_notebook.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

tk.Button(root, text='Some Text!').pack(fill=tk.X)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes! This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

I did what Pythonista suggested. It worked pretty well, but it modified other widget's behavior too as the theme is applied globally. For example, the text (OK or Cancel) on the "*askokcancel*" dialog box got left aligned instead of staying in the center. The easiest way I found which just adds padding and doesn't change any other behavior is:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_settings("default", {"TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [30, 30]}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

This still didn't work for me. what i need to do is:

```
style = ttk.Style()                     
current_theme =style.theme_use()
style.theme_settings(current_theme, {"TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [20, 5]}}})
```