# How to increase the font size of Tab header in tkinter Notebook?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, header, size

I have searched here for this query, but I didn't find an answer for this except setting up the font size of widgets [inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211530/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-tab-caption-box-and-font-of-ttk-notebook-tabs) the Notebook

As I mentioned in the title, I would like to increase the font size of Tab header. For example,

```
transaction_book = ttk.Notebook(frame)
transaction_book.place(relwidth=0.6, relheight=0.79, relx=1, rely=0.21, anchor='ne')

#Make 1st tab
f1 = tk.Frame(transaction_book)
#Add the tab
transaction_book.add(f1, text="Tab one")

#Make 2nd tab
f2 = tk.Frame(transaction_book)
#Add 2nd tab
transaction_book.add(f2, text="Tab two")

transaction_book.select(f1)
```

In the above code, I would like to increase the Tab headers "Tab One" and "Tab Two" to a bigger size.

Kindly suggest if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: "The other approach..." shown in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213658/355230) to the linked question shows how to change the font size of tab headers.

Comment: @martineau: I missed the 's.theme_use("MyStyle")' line in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution is,

```
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure('TNotebook.Tab', font=('URW Gothic L','15','bold'), padding=[10, 10])

    transaction_book = ttk.Notebook(frame)
    transaction_book.place(relwidth=0.6, relheight=0.80, relx=1, rely=0, anchor='ne')
```